# Flutter_web using google_sign_in

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am working on Flutter_web and migrating some of my app, since plugins are not ready, I have download the google sign in plugin and implemented in my code without using pubspec.yaml.  All seems to be checking out fine, except when I try to initial the `await _googleSignIn.signIn();` nothing happens, not even an error.  I just want it to ask the user for the google account they want to use, but nothing happens.  This is my first use of this plugin so not sure what else I am missing.  I see no where to put clientID or anything so not sure if its the code trying to run in web or if its something else I am missing.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, google_sign_in seems to have an explicit dependency on the Flutter SDK, which does not mix with flutter_web.

Follow this issue to track progress on merging the two: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34082

Comment: @Robert, flutter_web is now part of Fluter SDK (you have to use flutter master channel).